# Lua unable to find module

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to develop dissectors for wireshark. Since all my dissectors use the same port number, I plan on adding an extra dissector layer as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195317/how-wireshark-dissect-correctly-with-two-lua-dissectors-on-the-same-port).
I have proceeded with creating a generic dissector that verifies the type of packet and based upon that, it passes the packet data to the relevant dissectors. I have created different modules for different dissectors which I plan to include in my generic dissector.
In my generic dissector I am declaring the module using the require command.
module_name = require("module_name"). 
 However, upon doing so, when I run Wireshark, I am getting the following error: 
Lua: Error during loading:
C:\XXXX\generic_dissector.lua:1: module 'module_name' not found.

This is surprising since both my module and my generic dissector are lying in the same directory. Please let me know what could be done in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your module file put in the Personal Plugins Folder? You can look up the folder path from

`Help -> About Wireshark -> Folders -> Personal Plugins`

For OS X

`Wireshark -> About Wireshark -> Folders -> Personal Plugins`)

If not in that folder, try move your module there and re-run your dissector again.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help. Apparently the issue got solved after moving the module to -- Program Files \ Wireshark directory. But now I am having another issue with regards to the dissector. Basically I have are different types of packets that are captured at the same port number. I tried to create multiple lua dissectors and add them init.lua but upon doing so, some or the other dissector doesn't work. I am now trying to create a generic dissector that verifies the type of packet and subsequently sends the packet the corresponding dissector, however I am not sure how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Specifically I am not sure how to pass the packet data to a particular dissector and return its result to present it is a result of the generic dissector. Also I believe that if I create a generic dissector then I won't be able to apply a filter based on specific values of some attributes of a specific dissector. Please let me know if there is any way around it. Thanks.