# Wireshark Lua why doesn't multiple dissectors with same port number work in Wireshark

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have been trying to create dissectors for Wireshark using Lua. The issue is that I have different packets that use the same port number. I found out that one solution to this problem is to create a generic dissector that checks the type of packet and then sends the packet data to the corresponding dissector from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195317/how-wireshark-dissect-correctly-with-two-lua-dissectors-on-the-same-port). I am however not sure why doesn't multiple dissectors with same port number work in wireshark. 
Also I am not sure how to create the generic dissector. Specifically I am not sure how the generic dissector will pass the information to the specific dissector and how will it get back the information to display it. Another thing that I am doubtful about is that in the event I create a generic dissector, how should I design it such that I can select the types of packets to decode using the generic dissector. Please let me know what could be done in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to register your Lua dissectors as heuristic dissectors.  Refer to [Section 11.6.5.3](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Proto.html#lua_class_Proto) of the Wireshark Developer's Guide for the **`register_heuristic`** Lua function to do that.

If you're looking for Lua sample heuristic dissectors, I'd recommend visiting the Wireshark wiki and viewing some of the examples there, for example, the [dissector.lua](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples#A_dissector_tutorial_script) dissector located on the Wireshark Lua Examples wiki page.